# Spring JPA Criteria API native query with join giving org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I followed this article - https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-native-queries/ to get a list of generic objects from db in my spring boot project. Here's what I tried:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT t1.*, t2.name FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.t2_id = t2.id WHERE t2.type = 'TYPE'");
List<Object[]> resultList = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();
```

When the 2nd line is being executed, it's giving this error:

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

When using the same setup to run a query on single table and mapping it to its entity is going fine.

eg: Class1 is a JPA entity of table t1. This works fine for example.

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query_string, Class1.class)
```

Using PostgreSQL for this. My application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL 
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: Have you set the hibernate dialect in the application properties? Can you show us the file? What is your database?

Comment: @Lorelorelore - I added my application properties, but the nativeQuery with mapping is working fine as I wrote in the question.

Comment: Have you tried setting in application.properties the following property: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`?

Comment: No, but the other native query I showed in the question is working fine, so will that be the issue? And getting the same error even after adding that property

Comment: Actually I don't know... maybe there is some other characteristic of Hibernate that I miss. However I would try with the other property, maybe it is sufficient.

Comment: Added and checked, giving the same error

Comment: The error means that Hibernate encountered a type it doesn't know how to handle. If you examine the error more closely you'll find what type it can't handle, e.g. `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111`

This article describes one scenario where this occurs and multiple ways how to solve the issue: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type/ 

There are also SO questions for other variants (type #) of this error.

Comment: The different types in my table are uuid, varchar, timestamp & text[]. Not sure if these can't be hamdled by hibernate